# Can't use GeckoFX on another Thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, geckofx

I'm trying to change some geckofx prefrences from another backgroundWorker.

After starting the debug I'm getting this:

> {"GeckoFx can only be called from the same thread on which it was
>   initialized (normally the UI thread)."}

```
Public Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Do

        Thread.Sleep(10000)
        GeckoPreferences.User("general.useragent.override") = operalinux

        ualabel.Text = "operalx"

        Thread.Sleep(10000)
        GeckoPreferences.User("general.useragent.override") = operawin
        ualabel.Text = "operawin"


        Thread.Sleep(10000)
        GeckoPreferences.User("general.useragent.override") = CHROMELINUXUA
        ualabel.Text = "chromelux"
        Thread.Sleep(10000)
        GeckoPreferences.User("general.useragent.override") = CHROMEWINDOWSUA
        ualabel.Text = "chromewin"


        Thread.Sleep(10000)
        GeckoPreferences.User("general.useragent.override") = FIREFOXLINUXUA
        ualabel.Text = "FFLUX"

        Thread.Sleep(10000)
        GeckoPreferences.User("general.useragent.override") = FIREFOXWINDOWSUA
        ualabel.Text = "FFWIN"
        Thread.Sleep(10000)

    Loop
End Sub
```